# ASP.Net and Axiomatics

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authorization, xacml, abac

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com), for [Attribute Based Access Control](https://www.axiomatics.com/attribute-based-access-control/)?  I need to implement it into a project but have not used it before.  My project is an ASP.Net (written in VB.Net code behind) forms website (i.e. not MVC).  Does anyone know of a tutorial that will walk me through setting up claims in Axiomatics, then using these claims in my ASP.Net application?  I haven't had much luck with this.

thanks

Comment: Someone with your point count should know that such questions are off-topic.

Comment: Feel free to reach out to Axiomatics. I work there and we will gladly help you understand how to achieve ABAC with Axiomatics and the PEP SDK for .NET